# How to Reassign Work Items in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio Online (free with 2 users) & Visual Studio 2013, we can create work items and edit them both in the Visual Studio Online web access and Visual Studio 2013.

But when edit a work item in Visual Studio Online we can not reassign it to the other member in the project.  In Visual Studio 2013 we can.

Note: On work item creation all members are shown for selection.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new identity control was deployed with the Sprint 74 release.  You can simply start typing their name or part of their name & click Search.  Over time, you'll have a Most Recently Used (MRU) list built-up with the people you commonly assign work items to.  The new identity control will be released in a future Visual Studio update so that the experience will match.  Brian Harry has some additional comments about it in his [December 2nd Visual Studio Online Update blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/12/03/visual-studio-online-update-dec-2nd.aspx).  That's a good blog to subscribe to in addition to the new features blog available here:  http://www.visualstudio.com/news/release-archive-vso

[image: New Identity Control in Visual Studio Online]